# Streaming OpenAI completions in .NET web application

Tags: .net, azure, web-applications, stream, openai-api

Our team is building a chat-bot mentor for a short course in cooking, based on OpenAI's gpt-3.5-turbo which we access trough an API. Prompts and their completions can get rather big, sometimes needing half a minute to be completed (around 2000 tokens per prompt and 1000 per completion, and this is the bare minimum we managed to achieve) so we are forced to stream the response to improve UX.

However, as a data science team with mathematics an Python background, we are new to .NET. We exhausted all of the online resources regarding streaming the response in an .NET web app, and noticed that answers, if ever given, stream to console using console.write(chunk) and not the app itself, or do pseudo-streaming where they wait for the whole completion, split on words and then print as if the response was streamed.

**How could we go about this problem of streaming the OpenAI chat response to a web app and not just the console**? Given that, besides getting the input and then streaming the output everything is done in the background (using LangChain, Pinecone and MSSQL, we managed to create the whole 1000-lines-of-code-long infrastructure and got stuck at the streaming part), an extremely simple example would do - you could give the C#/.NET OpenAI api a prompt like "write a poem in 100 tokens", it is enough. All packages are allowed, just do not print in the console and do the pseudo-streaming trick.

What did not work:

- The "backend tricks" have been exhausted - we can not use recurrent self-feeding loops that create a sentence-by-sentence outputs in the background so that the illusion of the streaming is achieved or create the response segment-by-segment. The prompts and responses can not be shortened, there is a history being passed, context that is retrieved by semantic search and rules the model needs to follow. There are also helper bots that are there to detect "dangerous content" that work fine because their results are never being printed anywhere.
- We have spent around 16 worker-hours browsing and learning and have noticed that even the official Microsoft webpages print use console.write() when doing it. The official GitHub support usually closes the problem before the problem is solved.
- We have tried using azure functions, we get response all at once by doing this and are pretty sure HTTP responses from python can not stream (one script - one response).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use RageAgainstThePixel:
using var api = new OpenAIClient();
var messages = new List<Message>
{
    new Message(Role.System, "You are a helpful assistant."),
    new Message(Role.User, "Who won the world series in 2020?"),
    new Message(Role.Assistant, "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."),
    new Message(Role.User, "Where was it played?"),
};
var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(messages);
var response = await api.ChatEndpoint.StreamCompletionAsync(chatRequest, partialResponse =>
{
    Console.Write(partialResponse.FirstChoice.Delta.ToString());
});